# Calculate the trend of raster in R

Tags: r, time-series, raster, terra

I want to calculate the trend of the raster in a time series, but there is an error.

The below is the code.

```
library(terra)
trend <- function(x){
  if(is.na(x[1])){rep(NA,length(x))}
  else{
 summary(lm(as.numeric(x)~c(2015:2100)))$coefficients[2]
   }
}
data
class       : SpatRaster
dimensions  : 40, 81, 86  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.5, 0.5  (x, y)
extent      : 46.5, 87, 35.5, 55.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84
source(s)   : memory
names       :      y_2015,       y_2016,       y_2017,       y_2018,       y_2019,       y_2020, ...
min values  : 0.00000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, ...
max values  : 6.49618e-10, 6.122992e-10, 5.359198e-10, 6.447496e-10, 6.671828e-10, 6.464858e-10, ...
time (years): 2015 to 2100

data |> app(trend)

**Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=list; target=double].**
```

Comment: What package has the `app()` function.

Comment: The terra package, sorry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

please check the function [`regress`](https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/regress.html) in the latest version of `terra`package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).